# Proving $\sqrt x$ is continuous in $x=1$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

When I wanted to prove $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous at $x = 1,$ I did the following:
Let $\epsilon >0 $ arbitrary and chose $\delta = \epsilon^2-1$. Assume $0<|x-1|<\delta$. Then we get for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ :

$|f(x)-f(1)|=|\sqrt{x}-1|\le |\sqrt{\delta+1}-1|<\sqrt{\delta+1}=\epsilon$

Is my prove valid?. The other methods I saw which include taking $\delta=\epsilon$ seem to be better than what I did.

Comment: If epsilon is small your delta is negative! Won't work

Comment: Yeah, getting negative $\delta$ makes it invalid.

Comment: It's also not clear why $|x-1|<\delta$ implies $|\sqrt x-1|\leq \sqrt{\delta+1}-1.$ That is true, but it isn't trivially true - it is trivially true for $x>1,$ but not for $1-\delta<x<1.$

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is not valid. Note that
$$
|\sqrt x - 1| = \left| \frac{x - 1}{\sqrt x + 1} \right| \le |x - 1| \le \epsilon
$$
hence $\delta$ is selected as $\delta = \min(1, \epsilon)$. Comparing to $1$ ensures that $x$ is valid (i.e. not negative).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... this may not be helpful but the way I was taught in calc II was this

A function $f(x)$ is continuous at $c$ given that

1. $f(c)$ exists.
2. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = L$ exists.
3. $L = f(c)$

From this definition we can see that $\sqrt{1}$ does indeed exist (it is $1$).

The limit also exists because we can plug $1$ in and it yields $L=1$. To prove this, we will use standard epsilon delta proof.

> Given $\varepsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \varepsilon$.
>
> Suppose $0<|x-1|<\delta$. We we need to check the expression $\left|\sqrt{x}-L\right|=\left|\sqrt{x}-1\right|$. To do this, we multiply by the conjugate, yielding
> $$\left|\sqrt{x}-1\right|=\left|\frac{(\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}+1)}{\sqrt{x}+1}\right| = \frac{|x-1|}{|\sqrt{x}+1|} = \frac{|x-1|}{\sqrt{x}+1}\le |x-1| <\delta = \varepsilon$$

Now, we to to conclude, since the limit itself is $1$ and the function is also $1$ at $x=1$, the function must be continuous at $x=1$.

Comment: I did both actually

Comment: I think you meant to say 'Choose $\delta = \varepsilon$.'

Comment: @Aruralreader youre right oops lol

Comment: @muhammedgunes what do you mean by that btw?

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt x-1=\frac{x-1}{\sqrt x +1}$$ If $\vert x-1 \vert<1$ then $x>0$ and   so $\sqrt x +1>1$ and $$\frac{\vert x-1\vert}{\sqrt x +1}<\vert x-1 \vert$$ For $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta=\min(1, \epsilon)$. If $\vert x-1\vert<\delta$ then $\vert \sqrt x -1\vert<\epsilon$